# Are non-stationary ARMA models used to model time series?

Tags: time-series, arima, stationarity

An ARMA model is not necessarily stationary. It is when certain conditions on the model are satisfied.

In time series, an ARMA model is used to model a stationary process. On the other hand, is a nonstationary ARMA model used to model a (not necessarily stationary) time series? Or (almost) always, only stationary ARMA is used for modelling a time series?

The point of my question is whether nonstationary ARMA is useful or useless.

Comment: possible [duplicates](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/65193/why-is-arma-used-to-model-a-stationary-process)

Comment: @Metrics: In the other post, I am talking exclusively about stationary processes, and why ARMA can approximate them. Here I am asking about whether nonstationary ARMA is used for modelling any time series. Two different questions. Please read.

Comment: Please go through the answer for your earlier question by @ Arman

Comment: @Metrics: That is an answer to a different question.

Comment: The answer is yes; but you need to use ARIMA (which means you need to take the difference if ARMA is non-stationary).

Comment: A nonstationary ARMA is not ARIMA. It is still ARMA, but not stationary. The point of my question is whether nonstationary ARMA is useful or useless.

Comment: A non-stationary ARMA (2,3) means ARMA is say I(1), then it becomes ARIMA(2,1,3) which means if you difference `y` one time, then it becomes stationary ARMA.

Comment: @Metrics: So is nonstationary ARMA always converted to stationary ARMA? It is useless without conversion?

Comment: yes, for forecasting purpose you can't use non-stationary process

Comment: @Metrics: for forecasting purpose, is stationarity sufficient? Isn't stationarity and ergodicity both required?

Comment: Stationarity means weak stationary; I think ergodicity requires strict stationary.

Comment: @Metrics: For forecasting purpose, stationarity is not enough, whether it is weak or strict, isn't it? We still need ergodicity, do we? Shall I post it as a new question?

Comment: I am not sure how it is practiced in industry but in academia (and particularly in my field), the focus is on weak stationary.

Comment: By "not sure how it is practiced", do you mean how to transform the data to be ergodic and test its ergodicity?

Comment: I am saying that we don't test ergodicity but there are tests for testing ergodicity (google it)

Comment: Why "we don't test ergodicity"? I google it but not sure what are some standard ways to test ergodicity or transform a time series to be ergodic?

Comment: google the article [A consistent nonparametric test of ergodicity for time series with applications](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0304407601000586)

Comment: "The concept of ergodicity is fundamental in the analysis of economic time series and of dynamic models calibrated by time series data. It is, therefore, surprising that no general testing procedure has been proposed to examine this important hypothesis. The objective of this paper is to fill this gap for the case of Markov processes."

Comment: @Metrics: Thanks for the reference.  Back to "A non-stationary ARMA (2,3) means ARMA is say I(1), then it becomes ARIMA(2,1,3) which means if you difference y one time, then it becomes stationary ARMA", why is a nonstationary ARMA can be made stationary by differencing once? A ARIMA process is defined so that differencing can make it become a stationary ARMA. A nonstationary ARMA may not be made stationary by differencing?

Comment: A new question is posted regarding my last comment: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/65456/can-a-nonstationary-arma-always-be-made-stationary-after-differencing

Comment: If the above comments were helpful, I'd suggest @Metrics summarized them as an answer to close this thread.

Comment: @chl: I would like to do that, but I think this is a possible duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

Non-stationary ARMA includes both ARIMA and also "explosive" models (see related answer [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/401665/arma-vs-arima-models/502850#502850); I'll include the diagram below for convenience).  ARIMA models are widely used to model non-stationary processes, but "explosive" ARMA models are never really used in practice.  In theory they could be used to model explosive processes, but they tend to converge rapidly to deterministic exponential growth (either standard exponential growth or oscillating exponential growth), so they are barely even stochastic models at all.

[image]