# Can a nonstationary ARMA always be made stationary after differencing?

Tags: time-series

I was wondering if a nonstationary ARMA can always be made stationary after differencing? The question arises from Metrics' comment on [my previous question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/65281/are-non-stationary-arma-models-used-to-model-time-series):

> ... you need to use ARIMA (which means you need to take the difference if ARMA is non-stationary). – Metrics yesterday
>
> A non-stationary ARMA (2,3) means ARMA is say I(1), then it becomes ARIMA(2,1,3) which means if you difference y one time, then it becomes stationary ARMA. – Metrics yesterday

In the example he gave, why can a nonstationary ARMA(2.3) become ARIMA(2,1,3)? ARIMA is defined to be able to become **stationary** ARMA after differencing. How do we know a nonstationary ARMA(2.3) can become **stationary** ARMA after differencing?

Thanks and regards!

Comment: @ Tim: I assume that you are the beginner in applied time series econometrics. So, I recommend you to have a book Applied Econometric Times Series by [Walter and Enders](http://www.amazon.com/Applied-Econometric-Series-Probability-Statistics/dp/0470505397).

Comment: @Metrics: Thanks! Does the book address my question and where in it?

Comment: Yes, it will answer your question.It should be in chapter on ARMA.

Comment: @Metrics Walter Enders is precisely one author.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A process which is integrated of order one, $I(1)$, is stationary after differencing once. A process which is integrated of order $d$, $I(d)$, is stationary after differencing $d$ times. There are tests for determining the integration order of a time series, like the Dickey-Fuller test or KPSS test. E.g. If you find from a test, that the process is not stationary, you may difference it and run the test on the differenced series to see if it's still non-stationary.

Comment: Thanks! Does your reply mean that a nonstationary ARMA process may not be made stationary by differencing?

Comment: No, not necessarily. Only a $I(1)$ process is stationary after differencing once. A non-stationary process is any $I(d)$ process where $d\neq0$.

Comment: Do you mean any nonstationary process can always be made stationary after some number of differencing?

Comment: As far as I know. As I said, an $I(d)$ process is stationary after differencing $d$ times.

Comment: There are processes that are nonstationary and cannot be made stationary with any amount of differencing. For instance, add $\exp(t)$ to a stationary process $(x_t)$.

Comment: But this can be a trend-stationary process, right?

Comment: My example is first order non-stationary. You should have no trouble adapting it to create second order non-stationarity. For instance, consider Gaussian processes of the form $(x_t)$ where $x_t \sim N(0, \exp(t))$. No amount of differencing can make such processes stationary even though they have a constant zero mean.

Comment: @whuber: Thanks! What you and I think is that the time series is continuous-time. But the actual time series is always discrete-time by discretizing the continuous time, and keeping differencing a time series with finite number of time values, will eventually leave only one point. But I am still confused: a nonstationary ARMA process have countably infinite number of points

Comment: Please don't make assertions about what I think, Tim, because they might not be true. In particular, I haven't made any assumptions about what times are possible. *You* need to clarify what you're asking about, though: if you insist that your time series are actual data sets then, as you say, it's a triviality that $n-1$ differences will reduce them to nothing. But that's not what stationarity is about: it's a *theoretical* construct and applies, *sensu strictu,* only to mathematical models of time series, for which we may assume that $t \in \mathbb{N}$ for instance.

Comment: @whuber: in one of your previous comments, did you mean "adding exp(t) to a stationary process (xt)" is a "first-order nonstationary" (meaning $I(1)$?)? If yes, I think it is incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

Fredrikhs is correct.

You can keep differencing any non-stationary time series until you arrive at a series which is stationary. One downside, however, is that you lose an observation with each difference.

Comment: Thanks! why "you can keep differencing any non-stationary time series until you arrive at a series which is stationary"? What kind of observation do I lose with each difference?

Comment: Shouldn't this be a comment? @Tim: If you have a series of three variables, $t_1$, $t_2$ and $t_3$, when you difference, you lose one. After differencing these three variables you get, $\Delta t_1$ which is $t_1-t_2$, and $\Delta t_2$ which is $t_2-t_3$, can you see that you have lost one observation?

Comment: @fredrikhs: Is the reason "why a nonsationary time series can always made stationary" that we can keep differencing till only one observation is left, and a single observation is stationary trivially?

Comment: Not essentially. By differencing you decrease the integration order of the series by one. Most time series you will encounter is either $I(0)$, $I(1)$ or $I(2)$. But theoretically I guess they can be of even higher integration order. But the point is, the $d$'th difference of a $I(d)$ process is stationary. Except for the case @whuber mentioned.

Comment: Simply put, "stationary" just means that the statistical parameters (mean, variance, kurtosis, etc) don't change with time. You can see why your series would be stationary if you're down to your last observation...the mean of that one observation can't change because there's not other observation! This is an extreme example, but it illustrates the point. 

Hope that helps.

Comment: @fredrikhs and AO.: a nonstationary ARMA process has countably infinite number of points, and keeping differencing it will not reduce the number of points.

Comment: The number of observations is not really relevant for the concept of stationarity. I don't know how to explain it any further.