# What part of an ARMA model requires a stationary time series - the AR or the MA?

Tags: time-series, arima, stationarity

Could I use a non-stationary time series with simply an Autoregressive model?

Comment: No. ARMA is not a model for nonstationary time series. As part of ARMA culture, you first stationarize the data then apply ARMA.

Comment: MA is inherently stationary. Both the AR and MA components are assumed to be stationary in an ARMA model. If you can make it stationary by differencing, you can use ARIMA.

Comment: Related, https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/112154/28746

Answer (score 1):

I don't agree with the view that ARMA models are inherently stationary --- this is a convention imposed in many treatments of the subject to rule out explosive models and ARIMA models, but it is not a necessary implication of the core equation for this model.  Based on the mathematical form of the ARMA model, one can instead conceive of the class of ARMA models in either a broader or narrower sense, which either allows or disallows non-stationary cases (see this [related answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/65281/549581#549581)).  The restriction imposed on an ARMA model to ensure (weak) stationarity is a restriction on the AR part and a corresponding (implicit) assumption that the "anchor" distribution is already in stationary form (see this [related answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/330714330727#330727)).  For the AR part, stationarity requires that all the roots of the AR characteristic polynomoial lie outside the unit circle in the complex plane (see this [related answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/346448/346463#346463)).

Answer (score 0):

> What part of an ARMA model requires a stationary time series - the AR
> or the MA?

The AR parte require stationarity condition. As said in comments, the MA is inherently stationary; usual require for MA is invertibility.

> Could I use a non-stationary time series with simply an Autoregressive
> model?

For non-stationary case extensions like ARIMA was proposed. However, for example, if your series is an $ARIMA(p,1,q)$ process you can take the first difference and model it with ARMA.